# How to write this piece of code in function?

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am using the "Divergence Indicator" script written by Tradingview with Macd, stoch and rsi at the same time.
I use the code below duplicate 3 times (for Macd, stoch and rsi)

```
plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(rsi, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

// Regular Bullish  
oscHL = rsi[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
priceLL = close[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, close[lbR], 1)
bullCond = priceLL and oscHL and plFound
// Regular Bearish
oscLH = rsi[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, rsi[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])
priceHH = close[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, close[lbR], 1)
bear = priceHH and oscLH and phFound
```

Is it possible to use a function to avoid duplicating the same code 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple

```
f_divergences(_src) =>

   plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(_src, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
   phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(_src, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

  // Regular Bullish  
  oscHL = _src[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, _src[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
  priceLL = close[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, close[lbR], 1)
  bullCond = priceLL and oscHL and plFound
  // Regular Bearish
  oscLH = _src[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, _src[lbR], 1) and 
  _inRange(phFound[1])
  priceHH = close[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, close[lbR], 1)
  bear = priceHH and oscLH and phFound

  [bullCond, bear]

// Calling the function three times
[rsi_bull, rsi_bear] = f_divergences(rsi)
[stoch_bull, stoch_bear] = f_divergences(stoch)
[macd_bull, macd_bear] = f_divergences(macd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the logic of a function..